# How to point a chef client to a different chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I've set up a chef client on my computer in order to do practice using the labs offered by learnchef.com.

How do I now point my chef client to our internal chef servers( we have 2 non-production and production). Do you need to reconfigure `knife.rb` as well as recreate `validator.pem` and `client.pem` files?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to get the validator.pem from each server and register to each
Another option is to create a client on each server and save the private key.

For bootstraping other nodes you need the validator.pem file for each server.

I've the same use case and do the following:

1) create a directory per chef server containing a knife.rb, client.pem etc.
i.e:

```
c:\chef\confs\server1
c:\chef\confs\server2
```

2) set KNIFE_HOME environment variable to the directory matching the server you wish to target

```
set KNIFE_HOME=c:\chef\confs\server1
```

Now every knife command will target server1.

Another option is to set any environment variable you wish and use it in your knife.rb file like
    chef_server_url  ENV['CHEF_SERVER_I_USE']

But this last one involves having some other settings modified (like using server1.pem and server2.pem files and using the ENV[]  in the validator_key for exemple)

You can find an exemple of this method here (for users, but easy to adapt): http://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_knife.html

Comment: Checkout the knife block plugin. It can use the same convention of a directory for each chef server's files. The innovation it offers is to use links to point at a particular chef server's knife.rb. Additionally it's aware of Berkshelf's configuration files.

Comment: That's great on a linux workstation, not an XP one which has no clue about symlinks ;) I didn't test under win8, but using the KNIFE_HOME ENV var is quite OK for me. Maybe a pull request to the plugin to use ENV vars instead of symlinks under windows ...

Comment: Mark & Tensibai, Than you very much for your suggestions. I'll look ingot the knife block plugin. Tensibai, two questions 1) Do I need to reset KNIFE_HOME every time I need to point to a different server? 2)How do I created knife.rb, client.pem, etc files for each knife server. They were created automatically when I installed the client the first time. Thank you

Comment: You can set the environment variable and redo a knife initial, you need to know your server url and to have the corresponding validation key. I could post more detailed links tomorrow if needed

Comment: I copied admin.pem and chef-validator.pem into the C:/Chef/stg/chef-starter/chef-repo/.chef directory from the chef server. However, when I run 'knife configure -i' I get the following:

Comment: I copied admin.pem and chef-validator.pem into the C:/Chef/stg/chef-starter/chef-repo/.chef directory from the chef server. However, when I run 'knife configure -i' I get the following:You must place your client key in:
  C:/chef/stg/chef-starter/chef-repo/.chef/admin.pem
Before running commands with Knife!

*****

You must place your validation key in:
  C:/Chef/stg/chef-starter/chef-repo/.chef/chef-validator.pem
Before generating instance data with Knife!  I copied files from /etc/chef-server and both files are there.

Comment: Update: Got it to work! Uninstalled the chef client, created a new directory, copied the admin.pem and chef_validtor.pem from the server and rebuilt knife.br. After that I was able to run knife client list and got all the clients listed. Thank you for your help. I'll look into the knife block plug-in now.

Comment: If you end up using knife block, don't forget to flag Mark's answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Your chef client does not need to talk to more than one chef server. If you want to switch chef servers, then just delete the chef client's existing configuration and do a fresh bootstrap:

```
ssh $VM rm -rf /etc/chef
knife bootstrap $VM ...
```

Your chef workstation (your development machine that administers the chef servers) might want to access more than one chef server. In that case I recommend installing the [knife block](https://github.com/greenandsecure/knife-block) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For single-time interaction you may use `-s SERVER_URL` option like:

```
chef-client -S 'http://my_chef_server.net'
```

In case you need to change Chef Server forever, you have to edit `knife.rb` file. In order to interact with a Chef Server, three configuration settings are required, and you must change them.

```
node_name
client_key
chef_server_url
```

You may do it using `knife configure` command or manually with text editor(by default it lies in ~/.chef/knife.rb).

I would advise to you get familiar with that gist. It's [Commented knife.rb for all the things](https://gist.github.com/jtimberman/1718805). I believe it will help you to find out everything about configuring knife.